# When did Grace Murray Hopper say "The wonderful thing about standards is that there are so many of them to choose from?"

Tags: biographical-details, quote

When did Grace Murray Hopper say "The wonderful thing about standards is that there are so many of them to choose from?"  This quote is attributed to her in many places (including in one of my books), but I have never found the source of it. Does a source exist?

Answer (score 1):

According to [wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Andrew_S._Tanenbaum), it is due to Andrew S. Tanenbaum. It is taken from is book *Computer Networks*. The first edition appeared in 1980 (I don't know if it contains that sentence) and I confirmed that the fifth edition (2001) has the sentence.

Comment: @vy32 Please don't forget to post his answer here.

Comment: I'll ask Dr. Tanenbaum for a reference, and report back what I find.

Comment: It evidently appears  in Computer Networks (1981) on p. 168. https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper

Comment: I had thought that it was Yogi Berra. Regardless, it's definitely Yogi-esque.